# SelectMap: Should HSWAPEN be high?

Tags: fpga, spartan, selectmap

I'm in the process of debugging microprocessor loading of a Spartan 6 image through SelectMap. The HSWAPEN pin has caught my eye. In my design it is pulled low via a 10K resistor. However, when reading the status register I notice that the HSWAPEN pin is read as high, and I've confirmed this with an oscilloscope.

Is this behaviour normal? [This user guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug393.pdf) (see page 62) explains:

> HSWAPEN is a configuration-related multipurpose pin. When it is grounded prior to 
>   configuration, it enables internal pull-up resistors in all of the I/O pins of the device

Is HSWAPEN high because the internal pull-up is stronger than my pull-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the diagrams that I saw in the user guide as I took a quick pass have `HSWAPEN` tied directly to ground without a pull down resistor.

I couldn't find the `HSWAPEN` internal pull up resistance explicitly stated anywhere but [Table 4 in the Datasheet](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds162.pdf) gives the Thevenin equivalent resistance for programmable inputs and outputs. I'm assuming `HSWAPEN` would have a similar value since it can be used for User I/O after configuration. Depending on the grade device you are using, the values are different. But most are below 100Ω which would defiantly be stronger than your 10KΩ.

And here is a [Xilinx forum thread](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Spartan-Family-FPGAs/spartan-6-FPGA-i-o-state/td-p/116882/page/2) where a user states that 10KΩ is too high and that 0Ω should be used instead.